# Declare Variable based on conditions

Tags: sql

I would like to declare a variable @Grade following:

```
Declare @Grade varchar(max)''
Select @Grade = ...
```

With the following conditions needed to join tables:

If table1 subjectid exists in tableA id then select @Grade from tableA for each studentid

If table1 subjectid exists in tableB id then select @Grade from tableB for each studentid

If table1 subjectid exists in tableC id then select @Grade from tableC for each studentid

```
Sample Table1 - Student
Student ID   Subject ID   Rating
100          200          A
101          200          B
102          300          A
103          400          B
104
105          300          A

Sample TableA - Chinese
Subject ID  Rating      Grade
200         A           Good
200         B           Poor

Sample TableB - English
Subject ID  Rating       Grade
300         A            Good
300         B            Poor

Sample TableC - Maths
Subject ID  Rating       Grade
400         A            Good
400         B            Poor

Expected output:
Student ID   Subject ID   @Grade
100          200          Good
101          200          Poor
102          300          Good
103          400          Poor
104
105          300          Good
```

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: What rdbms? What is `table1 id`?

Comment: Please see the updated  tables, thanks

Comment: Nope. Not got a clue what you're trying to do here. I'm guessing that Tables 1, A, B and C here are your *sample data*? If so, what is the corresponding *expected result*?

Comment: Basically the aim is if either the subject id from the main Table1 exists in either Table A or B or C, then select the respective Grade from Table A or B or C for each student ID for each subject. And the Grade actually is a variable to be declared...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to produce your expected results:

```
declare @Student table (StudentID int not null,SubjectID int null,Rating char(1) null)
insert into @Student(StudentID,SubjectID,Rating) values
(100,200 ,'A'),    (101,200 ,'B'),    (102,300 ,'A'),
(103,400 ,'B'),    (104,null,null),    (105,300 ,'A')

declare @Chinese table (SubjectID int not null,Rating char(1) not null,Grade varchar(17) not null)
insert into @Chinese(SubjectID,Rating,Grade) values
(200,'A','Good'),    (200,'B','Poor')

declare @English table (SubjectID int not null,Rating char(1) not null,Grade varchar(17) not null)
insert into @English(SubjectID,Rating,Grade) values
(300,'A','Good'),    (300,'B','Poor')

declare @Maths table (SubjectID int not null,Rating char(1) not null,Grade varchar(17) not null)
insert into @Maths(SubjectID,Rating,Grade) values
(400,'A','Good'),    (400,'B','Poor')

select
    s.StudentID,
    s.SubjectID,
    COALESCE(c.Grade,e.Grade,m.Grade) as Grade
from
    @Student s
        left join
    @Chinese c
        on
            s.SubjectID = c.SubjectID and s.Rating = c.Rating
        left join
    @English e
        on
            s.SubjectID = e.SubjectID and s.Rating = e.Rating
        left join
    @Maths m
        on
            s.SubjectID = m.SubjectID and s.Rating = m.Rating
```

Result:

```
StudentID   SubjectID   Grade
----------- ----------- -----------------
100         200         Good
101         200         Poor
102         300         Good
103         400         Poor
104         NULL        NULL
105         300         Good
```

Note though that your current table design doesn't help us here - I'm unclear on why we have three separate tables for subject marking schemes - all of the data appears like it could appear in a single table and that would substantially simplify the above query.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Indeed the Chinese, English and Maths table are just sample tables that help easier express my question here, actual situation the tables are really three separate tables to store the information...

Comment: Hi Damien,
I have the error: The multi-part identifier "c.Grade,e.Grade,m.Grade" could not be bound.

How do the SQL recognize "s.", "e." and "m." as the three declared variable tables?